# Hide/Show - createBottomTabNavigator v6 tabBar in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

is it possible to hide/show the tabbar on scroll.

I need to hide/show **tabBar** on scroll up/down - when you scroll down the page the tabbar disappears and when you scroll back up it reappears. is it's only possible with a custom tabbar? - I'm currently using `"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9"`

I had adding onScroll event in my **FlatList** and tried to update tabBarVisible Status **true/false**. but no changes found.

````
        const currentOffset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
        let direction = currentOffset > offset ? "down" : "up";
        offset = currentOffset;
        if (direction === "down") {
            console.log("down")
            navigation.dispatch(
               navigation.setOptions({
                    tabBarVisible: false,
                })
            );
        } else {
            console.log("up")
            navigation.dispatch(
                navigation.setOptions({
                    tabBarVisible: true,
                })
            );
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try to change tabBar display style prop

**EDITED**

```
    const [ offset, setOffset ] = useState(0);
    
   
const hideTabBar = () => {
        navigation.setOptions({
          tabBarStyle: { display: 'none' },
        });
      };
const showTabBar = () => {
        navigation.setOptions({
          tabBarStyle: { display: 'flex' },
        });
      };
    
             const currentOffset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
                    let direction = currentOffset > offset ? "down" : "up";
                    if (direction === "down") {
                        console.log("down")
                        hideTabBar()
                    } else {
                          console.log("up")
                          showTabBar()
                    }
                    setOffset(currentOffset)
```

Read more: https://mobiledevtutorials.com/how-to-hide-tab-bar-from-screen-in-react-navigation-6/

Comment: I tried adding tabBarStyle too already. But no changes found.

Comment: Remove **navigation.dispatch**

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@xyanz/hide-show-tab-bar